# How to set multiple conditions depending on Binding and Property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so I have a simple DataGrid. I have 4 colors to be displayed for the rows.

1. Default-Row-Backgroundcolor: Green -> default backgroundcolor
2. Default-Row-Hover-Backgroundcolor: DarkGreen -> when hovering over 1.
3. UnfinishedEntry-Backgroundcolor: Red -> if Binding Property Time=NULL
4. UnfinishedEntry-Hover-Backgroundcolor: DarkRed -> when hovering over 3.

Implementing 1. and 2. is simple, just set the default to Green and onHovering to DarkGreen.
For 3. I use a simple DataTrigger.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Time}"  Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource RedBackgroundColor}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

But how would I implement 4.?
I would've used a Multidatatrigger like

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding Time}"  Value="{x:Null}"/>
         <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/> 
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource RedBackground}"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

But the code above won't work. Seems like this line is causing problems when using Property in a DataTrigger:

> Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to possibly solve my question.
I thought it was some kind of referencing problem, as using a DataTrigger may not know about the Properties of a Control like a Trigger would, so I had to reference it differently.

That's what I came up with and it is working as intended now:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
```